# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create'). Happens when running npm run build:ssr

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Getting an error when running npm run build:ssr to try to deploy my angular application
The error:

> firestarter@0.0.0 compile:server
> webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors

C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
throw err;
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
at Object. (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\webpack.server.config.js:5:39)
at Module._compile (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
at requireConfig (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
at C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
at Array.forEach ()
at module.exports (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
at C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:71:45
at Object.parse (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:576:18)
at C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8
at Object. (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:366:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at runCli (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:54:2)
at Object. (C:\Users\2998542\Documents\DeveloperPortfolio\Projects\firestarter\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:147:2)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

See the code below that the error is pointing to.
I've been trying to figure out why is giving me that error for weeks now.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackConfigFactory = require('@nestjs/ng-universal')
  .WebpackConfigFactory;

module.exports = WebpackConfigFactory.create(webpack, {
  // Nest server for SSR
  server: './server/main.ts'
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`WebpackConfigFactory` no longer exists as Angular is now using CLI Builders to build & serve SSR apps.

[Issue reported here](https://github.com/nestjs/ng-universal/issues/418)